# The options don't work when creating my chart using chartjs (4.3.0) with react-chartjs-2 (5.2.0)

Tags: typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs, date-fns

My bar chart is displayed with the correct data, but I can't change the text color on the 2 axes or the date formatting. It's like Options are not read.
I'm using React 18.2.0 and typescript 4.9.3.
Some datas are Date so i have installed date-fns (2.30.0) and its adapter chartjs-adapter-date-fns (3.0.0) as described in the ChartJs documentation.

This is my data :

```
const DetailsData: {
  time: string;
  loadPower: string;
}[] = [
  {
    time: '2023-01-18T02:00:00Z',
    loadPower: '2.6',
  },
  {
    time: '2023-01-18T02:15:00Z',
    loadPower: '2.4',
  },
  {
    time: '2023-01-18T02:30:00Z',
    loadPower: '2.3',
  },
]
```

This is my code component :

```
import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';
import { Chart as ChartJS } from 'chart.js/auto';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import DetailsData from './Data';

// Keep warn to avoid error "Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID '' can be reused.""
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.warn(ChartJS);

function PowerChart() {
  const barData = {
    labels: DetailsData.map((data) => data.time),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Load Power in KwH',
        data: DetailsData.map((data) => data.loadPower),
        backgroundColor: '#00aae1',
        borderColor: '#00aae1',
        borderWidth: 1,
        color: '#ffffff',
        font: 'Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif !default;',
      },
    ],
  };
  const barOptions = {
    options: {
      plugins: {
        scales: {
          x: {
            ticks: {
              color: '#ffffff',
            },
          },
          y: {
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              unit: 'hour',
            },
            ticks: {
              color: 'white',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
  // });

  return (
    <div className="chartBox">
      <Bar
        options={barOptions}
        data={barData}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default PowerChart;
```

I followed the [installation instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-adapter-date-fns) for chartjs-adapter-date-fns but the import of 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns' makes an error :

*Could not find a declaration file for module 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns'. 'c:/Users/XXX/frontend/node_modules/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.esm.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/chartjs-adapter-date-fns` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';*

I have tried the "npm i --save-dev @types/chartjs-adapter-date-fns" as indicated but it was not found.

I also followed the structure suggested in the react-chartjs-2 doc [here](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/examples/vertical-bar-chart)
I got an error on the options={barOptions} of bar element :
*
Type '{ options: { plugins: { scales: { x: { ticks: { color: string; }; }; y: { type: string; time: { unit: string; }; ticks: { color: string; }; }; }; }; }; }' has no properties in common with type '_DeepPartialObject<CoreChartOptions<"bar"> & ElementChartOptions<"bar"> & PluginChartOptions<"bar"> & DatasetChartOptions<"bar"> & ScaleChartOptions<...> & BarControllerChartOptions>'.ts(2559)

types.d.ts(19, 5): The expected type comes from property 'options' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<ChartProps<"bar", string[], string>, "type"> & { ref?: ForwardedRef<ChartJSOrUndefined<"bar", string[], string>>; }'

(property) options?: _DeepPartialObject<CoreChartOptions<"bar"> & ElementChartOptions<"bar"> & PluginChartOptions<"bar"> & DatasetChartOptions<"bar"> & ScaleChartOptions<...> & BarControllerChartOptions>*

I also got an error if i delete the console.warn at the top as indicated in the comment...

This is my first question on Stackoverflow. I hope i don't forget anything.
Somebody can help me ?

In the beginning, i tried to format my date data directly with a function in vanilla JS but I always get an invalid Date on the second render of react strict mode (first render was good!) so i come to date-fns as recommended in chartjs doc.
I tried to break up my code with a child component containing data and options in props (in fact, this was my first attempt).
I also tried inserting the plugins syntax in the options.

I really need to change the color of the font tick and display time like this : 03:00 (without date)

I read some stuff already here but it seems to be to old and i think the versionning maybe have to do with my problems. This is my first question on Stackoverflow. I hope i don't forget anything.
Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

About color, your chart options are wrong because you defined `scales` inside the `plugins` and that's wrong.
The correct is:

```
  const barOptions = {
    options: {
      scales: {
        x: {
          ticks: {
            color: '#ffffff',
          },
        },
        y: {
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            unit: 'hour',
          },
          ticks: {
            color: 'white',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

IMO it's better to submit a question for a specific topic and not put many topics in the same question as you did ;)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
Unfortunatly, i already tried on first place to put scales directly in the options part but it wasn't working, that's whay i tried to insert into  plugins.
I think you're right about the complexity of my question and that I should break it up into several topics.
I'll do that.